# Generating and inserting raw image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have a simple function plotter, located here: http://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/online-graphing-calculator/

It uses JavaScript and Canvas.

What I want to do next is to allow other people to link to raw output (pure image) of the graph (after they drew required plot).

For example, another person could insert on his page: `<img src="emathhelp.net/calculator/online-graphing-calculator?data=some_options&raw=true"/>`

The problem I encountered is that img tag expects binary data, so image should be generated on server.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any way I can embed javascript?

Can I avoid using server-side JavaScript, like Node.js?

Also, DOM structure should be available.

Thanks.

Comment: But in your sample you have a base 64 data var....you can use that in your img src

Comment: Not my img src. Img src from another site.

Comment: But you're using SVG on your site, not Canvas. If it would be Canvas, then you could call `canvasElement.toDataURL('image/png')` and then you could insert to the page like this: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,your-data-url-here">` without using server-side